# joomla database is not responding

Tags: mysql, joomla

In the joomla 3.7 site, everything was running OK. But last night suddenly it has gone totally down, throwing error msg

> "Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL"

The last operation performed by me was editing a comment as admin. When clicked "SAVE" after editing, the error appeared. The tables were MYIASM.

The check_database or repair_database option  in cpanel also do not respond. In phpMyAdmin, I can view the table list but running any query is halting with error

> "Lost connection to MySQL server during query

.

Can not back up the database either from cpanel or phomyadmin or mysqldump.

> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

But I have another drupal database in the same host. Tt is serving the site and all the above operation work on it without any problem.

The joomla db was in myIASM format. after all errors, I tried to convert the tables to InnoDB. But the ALTER TABLE query also halted in middle. Some tables are Innodb and some are MYIASM now.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Update:
After some checking, I found that the database is throwing error as

> already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections when
> trying to connect

But there is no active connection visible in "show processlist"

Answer (score 0):

In your .cfg or .ini,
log_warnings=2   for logging to your error log, including connection failure details.

To determine how many connections are possible,

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'
and increase by 10% with

max_connections=(newlimit)

both within [mysqld], shutdown, restart

remember SET GLOBAL general_log=1 will track everything MySQL is trying to do  for your analysis when you are having troubles.

Remember to turn OFF general_log before you go to lunch (or anywhere).